# OpenLDAP use of ObjectSid from Windows AD

Tags: openldap, syntax

I am creating a docker OpenLDAP to make a test  that is simpler than Active Directory.

To do this I have extracted a part of User account in a LDIF. I need the ObjectSid attribute because one of the devices I use needs it.

My issue is that when I ldapsearch to find the objectSid, it does not work. The server response returns no results.

I added attributeType ObjectSid with OctetString syntax and configured the classes to accept this attribute.

Is there anything else to configure to make this request work?

- LdapSearch request:

> ```
> ldapsearch -x -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" \
>            -W -H ldap://localhost:1389 -b "ou=ou2,ou=ou1,dc=example,dc=com" \
>            -s sub "(objectSid=\01\05\00\00\00\00\00\05\15\00\00\00\3f\dc\19\da\76\a9\a8\1a\d7\f2\25\4e\90\04\00\00)"
> ```

Comment: Is the device searching for a binary objectSid or is it searching for a `S-1-...` string? (AD has a special matching rule to allow both; your OpenLDAP server doesn't.)

Comment: it is searching for a binary objectSID, the one i put in my ldapsearch request

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it.
In my attribute schema, the parameter `EQUALITY octetStringMatch` was missing. So it was not able to make research as expected.